# Adding both Django_filter and pagination to FilterView class in django

Tags: django, filter, pagination

I am using the `django_filters` lib to filter my list views, here is the filter form :

```
class WorkerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ['id', 'branch']
```

here is how the **view** looks :

```
class WorkerListView(FilterView):
    model = Worker
    paginate_by = 1
    filter_class = WorkerFilter
    template_name = 'erp_system/worker_list.html'
    filterset_fields = ['id', 'branch']

    def get_queryset(self):
        new_context = Worker.objects.filter(
            active=True,
        )
        return new_context
```

And am using the form inside the HTML template this way :

```
   <form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p}}
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> بحث </button>
</form>
```

And at the end of this HTML page I have the list and the paginator this way :

```
        {% for item in filter.qs %}
{{item}}<br>
{% endfor %}
        {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"><button class="btn-success">الصفحة السابقة</button> </a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                     صفحة رقم  {{ page_obj.number }} من {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"><button class="btn-success">الصفحة التالية</button> </a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

The paginator part is not showing even when I used `paginate_by = 1` to debug it and make sure that `{% if is_paginated %}` works

Comment: I dont see anywhere you have imported and  used pagination!

Comment: `paginate_by = 1` works great in the `ListView`, The same way I used here. But I can't get it to work on the `FilterView`